# Apache kafka producer does not store data

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, java

I am trying to access kafka deployed on AWS server with public IP , however when trying to connect it and send some data i receive no response and the server connection is closed.Following is my producer code --

```
public SensorDevice() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("metadata.broker.list", "myip-xyz:9092");
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "myip-xyz:9092");
     props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
    props.put("key.serializer",
            "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    props.put("value.serializer",
            "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    // props.put("partitioner.class", "example.producer.SimplePartitioner");
    props.put("request.required.acks", "1");
    producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);

}

public void run() {

    Object objectData = new Object();

    ProducerRecord<String, String> data = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(
            topic, "mytopic", objectData.toString());
    System.out.println(data);
    Future<RecordMetadata> rs = producer.send(data,
            new org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata recordMetadata,
                        Exception arg1) {
                    System.out.println("Received ack for partition="
                            + recordMetadata.partition() + " offset = "
                            + recordMetadata.offset());
                }
            });

    try {
        String msg = "";
        RecordMetadata rm = rs.get();
        msg = msg + " partition = " + rm.partition() + " offset ="
                + rm.offset();
        System.out.println(msg);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    producer.close();

}
```

I have also tried adding advertise.host.name to server.properties config file.
Kafka shows following error --

```
>     [2015-04-24 09:06:35,329] INFO Created log for partition [mytopic,0] in /tmp/kafka-logs with properties {segment.index.bytes ->
> 10485760, file.delete.delay.ms -> 60000, segment.bytes -> 1073741824,
> flush.ms -> 9223372036854775807, delete.retention.ms -> 86400000,
> index.interval.bytes -> 4096, retention.bytes -> -1,
> min.insync.replicas -> 1, cleanup.policy -> delete,
> unclean.leader.election.enable -> true, segment.ms -> 604800000,
> max.message.bytes -> 1000012, flush.messages -> 9223372036854775807,
> min.cleanable.dirty.ratio -> 0.5, retention.ms -> 604800000,
> segment.jitter.ms -> 0}. (kafka.log.LogManager)
>     [2015-04-24 09:06:35,330] WARN Partition [mytopic,0] on broker 0: No checkpointed highwatermark is found for partition [mytopic,0]
> (kafka.cluster.Partition)
>     [2015-04-24 09:07:34,788] INFO Closing socket connection to /50.156.87.157. (kafka.network.Processor)
```

Please help me resolve this issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EC2 IP addresses are internal. You may face some issues when dealing with EC2 server running kafka and zookeeper. Try setting `advertised.host.name` and `advertised.port` variables in your `server.properties` file.

`advertised.host.name` should be IP address of the EC2 server.
`advertised.port` should be kafka port. By default it is `9092`.